# Universe inside atom

Tags: cosmology, universe, subatomic

It's not my personal theory.
Many scientists raised questions about this:

https://news.softpedia.com/news/Top-Physicists-Ponder-On-the-Idea-of-Universe-In-An-Atom-93428.shtml

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Universe_in_a_Single_Atom

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-WpmDgSjH0

I know that there isn't evidence to support this theory, but is there evidence against it? I mean, is there anything that we know that would make this theory impossible ?

Comment: it's true. I verified this experimentally by hitting one with a stick.

Comment: There's no theory here to comment on.  #1 appears to be a joke article (conference isn't named, photo seems silly, can't find many individuals named), #2 is an article on a non-scientific book, #3 is a non-scientific video.  The references are all about different things, not a single hypothesis.

Comment: The point is - many people thought about this scenario

Comment: physics is not about "scenario" and contemplation. It is about hypothesis  supported by **mathematical proof**  fitting data. and predicting falsifiable set ups. Is this "scenario" predicting  measurements that can validate it or falsify it?

Answer (score 2):

*Physics actually understands atoms really well*. Since 1900 a theory that accurately describes the behaviour of atoms and their components has been developed, tested, refined and put to use in a myriad of ways. And the picture given by quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, the standard model and their combinations doesn't at all look like anything you find in cosmology.

Cosmology and atomic physics are as dissimilar as cars and ducks. Sure, maybe cars and ducks "deep down" are exactly the same kind of thing, but it doesn't look like a promising area of inquiry.